# Ubuntu 14.04 scroll to focus on launcher behaviour broken

Tags: launcher, 14.04, mouse-scroll, focus

Back in Ubuntu 13.10 if you had multiple windows of the same application open and scrolled over that application's launcher icon it would bring up all the open windows one by one.

Now in Ubuntu 14.04 it will only focus one window at a time while minimizing the rest.

How can the previous behaviour be restored?

I mainly use this feature to bring up multiple file manager windows to transfer files from one window to the next or many other similar situations to view multiple windows at once. The new behaviour is much less practical.

Thank you.

Edit (thanks to fossfreedom for suggesting clarification):

(example)

In 13.10 if I'm in Firefox and I have 3 nautilus windows running behind Firefox and I scroll over the Nautilus icon 1 click brings the first window in front of Firefox, 2 clicks the second window, 3 clicks the third window, 4 clicks puts the first window back in focus but all 3 are visible in front of Firefox. In 14.04 I can only see the window that is in focus in front of Firefox, when I scroll to the next window, the previous one goes back behind Firefox. After 4 clicks, only 1 window is visible

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G3To8z81Ygw

Since I'm not getting any response or help using Ask Ubuntu, here is a link to the forum post: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2227315

I've also noticed with multiple different applications open sometimes multiple windows come up in front or behind of other applications. I would describe this feature now as severely broken.

example: with multiple file manager windows open and firefox in the background and using, say, a text editor, if the text editor is in focus, then I bring a fm window in focus, then go back to firefox, if I scroll on the fm launcher icon it will bring up one window at a time, putting each one back behind firefox as I go to the next, but the one that had the text editor behind it will bring up the text editor in front of firefox, behind the fm window.

Comment: I have the same question and couldn't find any answer yet. :(

Comment: scrolling on a launcher icon does not minimize windows of that app, not sure why you've inc. that in question title & in description

Comment: @doug: good point. I have changed my question title